# Настроить подключение к базе данных Амазона в application.properties в Spring Boot

Tags: база-данных, spring, spring-boot, amazon, amazon-web-services

Здравствуйте.

У меня есть Spring Boot приложение, которое локально подключается к базе данных MySQL через application.properties следующим образом:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:mysql://localhost:3306/dbname
spring.datasource.username = someusername
spring.datasource.password = somepassword
spring.jpa.show-sql = true
spring.jpa.hibernate.ddl-auto = update
spring.jpa.properties.hibernate.dialect = org.hibernate.dialect.MySQL5Dialect
```

Теперь я готовлю приложение к деплою на Амазон. Я создал там базу данных. [Здесь](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/elasticbeanstalk/latest/dg/java-rds.html) написано, что после создания я получил следующие переменные среды:

RDS_HOSTNAME – The hostname of the DB instance.

RDS_DB_NAME – The database name, ebdb.

RDS_USERNAME – The username that you configured for your database.

RDS_PASSWORD – The password that you configured for your database.

RDS_PORT – The port on which the DB instance accepts connections. The default value varies between DB engines.

Вопрос: могу ли я прописать эти переменные в своем application.properties и ограничиться этим, или же нужны дополнительные настройки?

Я много перечитал по этому поводу, но так и не нашел примера настроек с этими переменными.

Буду очень благодарен за пример настроек.

Comment: А что мешает вам попробовать? ;-)

Comment: Я попробовал, получаю от Амазона ошибку

Caused by: com.mysql.cj.core.exceptions.CJCommunicationsException: Communications link failure

Comment: Приложите обновленные конфиги (без паролей/логинов, естественно) и полный стек-трейс, возможно, там есть что-нибудь полезное.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

@ortex прав, именно так нужно прописывать в application properties, а именно:

```
spring.datasource.url = jdbc:postgresql://${RDS_HOSTNAME}:${RDS_PORT}/${RDS_DB_NAME}
spring.datasource.username = ${RDS_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password = ${RDS_PASSWORD}
```

Сначала у меня это не работало, поскольку нужно было внести еще два изменения:

Главный класс прописать в таком виде:

```
@SpringBootApplication
public class Application extends SpringBootServletInitializer {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SpringApplication.run(Application.class, args);
    }

    @Override
    protected SpringApplicationBuilder configure(SpringApplicationBuilder builder) {
        return builder.sources(Application.class);
    }
}
```

А также добавить в pom.xml следующую зависимость:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-tomcat</artifactId>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2):

Попробуй что-то типа

```
spring.datasource.username = ${RDS_USERNAME}
spring.datasource.password = ${RDS_PASSWORD}
```